# Unable to compile program with twitcurl

Tags: c++, linux, twitter

I want to compile a C++ program with a twitter library, on Linux.

I'm current using twitcurl as the twitter API library and installed g++ and all the necessary files and packages that are listed on the official website: http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/wiki/WikiHowToUseTwitcurlLibrary

However, when I compile my program using this command `g++ twitterClient.cpp -ltwitcurl`, I get this error: `cannot find -ltwitcurl`

I also used CodeBlocks IDE to compile it but got this error: `undefined reference to twitCurl::~twitCurl()`
`

My code only contains a few lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Twitter/Twitter.hpp"
using namespace std ;

int main ()
{
    Twitter t ;
    return 0 ; 
}
```

I've already spent a lot of time on this but am unable to solve the problem. What should I do in order to compile the program on the command-line and CodeBlocks?

Comment: Have you linked the implementation of the library? Sound like you have forgotten to link the .lib (Or .dll) of the library.

Comment: can u give some example on link the .lib ?? Are u say about the "libtwitcurl.so.1." ?

Comment: There are many questions answering something very similar. You need to understand how to invoke `g++` (and probably how to use `make`)

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ g++ twitterClient.cpp -ltwitcurl
cannot find -ltwitcurl
```

This means your compiler doesn't find the `libtwitcurl.so.1.` in its library directories.

First, make sure you correctly build the *twitcurl* library and obtained the `libtwitcurl.so.1.` file with something like this :

```
svn co http://twitcurl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/libtwitcurl
cd libtwitcurl/
make
```

Secondly, make sure you put the file (or a symlink) in one of your compiler's library path :

```
cp libtwitcurl.so.1.0 /usr/lib/
```

You can check g++ library paths using the following command :

```
g++ --print-search-dirs | grep libraries
```

(`/usr/lib/` is usually at the end.)

If you don't want/can't put the file in your compiler's library path, you can also tell it where to find `libtwitcurl.so.1.` by adding `-L/path/to/twitcurl/` in the g++ options, but it is not needed if the file is already in one of the compiler's library path.

Comment: I already copy the libtwitcurl.so.1. into /usr/lib/ but still shown "cannot find -ltwitcurl" 
If i want to use the last option, the command is like this ? 
"g++ twitterClient.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -ltwitcurl"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify path to twitter lib:

```
g++ twitterClient.cpp -L/path/to/lib/dir -ltwitcurl
```

Comment: still get the error , is the command like this ? "g++ twitterClient.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -ltwitcurl"