# How to statically link a library in a C/C++ application?

Tags: c++, c, static-linking

I'm trying to link a library called 'twitcurl.lib' in my application. I've tried researching things online and not much has turned up, or it's been quite confusing. Honestly I'm completely new to this - any ideas on how create this link?

Comment: How exactly you link the library to your program depends on what compiler (and IDE) you are using. Googling with that additional information should bring up some instructions/tutorials

Comment: May be [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) or [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this/24715865#24715865) link are helpful to solve your problems.

Comment: What compiler and build tools are you using? Have you consulted the reference material for it?

Comment: `twitcurl.lib` points to windows environment maybe?

Answer (score 5):

You are sure you already read all of the following links about the topic?

- [**How to use twitcurl library?**](https://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/wiki/WikiHowToUseTwitcurlLibrary)
- [**Unable to compile program with twitcurl**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299097/unable-to-compile-program-with-twitcurl)
- [**building twitcurl in visual studio 2010**](http://protomatic.blogspot.de/2013/01/building-twitcurl-in-visual-studio-2010.html)
- [**Unable to compile program with twitcurl**](http://www.coderexception.com/C6b6b3uHUiPiiWiy/unable-to-compile-program-with-twitcurl)
- ...

... and that many, many more links, you'll find on a [simple research](https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=MyPQU8PXIYeX_Aac34H4Cw&gws_rd=ssl#q=lib%20twitcurl%20linking%20error) about this question.
Clarify your question about your particular development environment and error messages please.

---

Besides the issues arising with this particular library, try to answer these questions first (and [***add additional information and appropriate tags***](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24920598/edit) to your question please):

- Which [**IDE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) are you using ([eclipse-cdt](/questions/tagged/eclipse-cdt), [codeblocks](/questions/tagged/codeblocks),[visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio))?
- Which [**toolchain**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain) are you using ([gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), [clang](/questions/tagged/clang), [msvc](/questions/tagged/msvc))?
- What's your development machine OS ([windows](/questions/tagged/windows), [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), [osx](/questions/tagged/osx))?
- For which [**target OS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897289/what-is-cross-compilation) you want to compile finally ([windows](/questions/tagged/windows), [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), [freertos](/questions/tagged/freertos), [bare-metal](/questions/tagged/bare-metal))?

For the above questions there are already answers available on SO, that might be applicable  for your particular [use-case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case):

- [***What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)
- [***Problems importing libraries to my c++ project, how to fix this?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715864/problems-importing-libraries-to-my-c-project-how-to-fix-this/24715865#24715865)